# Java Language Design with toString

Tags: java, language-design

We did they make the decision to not implement a `toString` method for `int[]`, but instead let it inherit the `toString` method from `Object`?

Comment: In case you need the functionality … do you know about `java.util.Arrays.toString` …?

Comment: @Konrad, but it is a poor design choice to use a utility class, just a pragmatic one IMHO.

Comment: @Peter: I wasn’t defending it. As far as I’m concerned, Java is a *series* of poor design choices.

Comment: @Konrad, over 16 years, you are bound to make a few.  Not everyone agrees on how best to fix them. ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They did implement more reasonable `toString` methods for arrays. They are located in the [`java.util.Arrays`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) class.

As for reasoning. I'm assuming by the overrides provided in the `Arrays` class, that trying to implement a generic `toString` for different types of arrays is either complex or impossible. The `toString` method would have to know what type of array it was working on, and output the data approrpiately. For instance, `Object[]` must use `toString` on each element, while `char[]` must output the character, and the numeric datatypes must be converted to a numeric string.

The methods in `Arrays` get this for free, because the types are fixed due to the overrides.

Comment: Actually changing Object to have a sensible toString() for arrays is pretty easy, just not recommended. Even better int[] has its own class and it knows its type could just do what toString(int[]) does.

Comment: `changing Object to have a sensible toString() for arrays`? Are you suggesting to patch sun source code?

Comment: Sun makes fixes and releases to the source code all the time, Java 6 is up to update 21.

Answer (score 2):

I guess because of the following reasoning: how would they know how users would want to present their array?  It might "array size: 10" or it might be "[x,y,z]".

They gave you a default, if you want to make it something else it is easy to do.

You can use apache's ToStringBuilder make it easier...

http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/ToStringBuilder.html

Comment: Not only this but it may be disastrous to call `toString()` on an array with 100,000 elements in it. And the purpose of `toString()` isn't just to display the contents of an object, but also to display a human-readable form to display in tools, debuggers, etc

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be is that because Array objects weren't created in Java source code by the language designers - they are created by the Java compiler.  Remember, you can have an array of any object type and so the compiler creates the Array object as appropriate for the type you require.

If they were to create a standard method, it's not immediately obvious how this should work.  For example, executing `toString()` and concatenating the results might be OK for a small array but it doesn't work for a multidimensional array or an array with 1,000 entries.  So I think no `toString()` method is created to keep all arrays consistent.

Admittedly, it is annoying and sometimes I do think something along the lines of `"Array[" + size + "] of " + getClassName()` would be so much better than the default.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of guesswork here, but...

There isn't an obvious string representation of an int array. People do it in different ways: comma separated, space separated, enclose in brackets or parentheses or nothing. That probably drove the decision not to implement it in Java 1.1, along with it being low priority code (since anyone can implement a method to write an array as a string themselves very simply).

Now you can't upgrade it in Java 1.2 or later because that would break back compatibility for anyone already using the old behaviour. You can however add a utility class that implements some functionality, and that's what they did with java.util.Arrays.