# Printing HashMap values (those values are Arrays) error

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

I've been trying and seeking for questions which are similar to mine for almost 2 days hope I will find out the answer, but no, I couldn't so I decided to ask you guys here.

This method is to print out all the keys and values of a `HashMap<String, int[]>` `ratingmap`. So keys are `String`s and values are arrays. I've been working on that and below is my code.

```
public void showRatingsMap() {
    for (String customer: ratingmap.keySet()) {
        String key = customer.toString();
        int[] value = ratingmap.get(key);
        System.out.println("Customer: " + key + " - Rating: " + value);
    }
}
```

I'm really confused at the moment because the result which is printed out looks like this:

```
Customer: Douglas Anderson - Rating: [I@4f5b571e
Customer: Sidney - Rating: [I@75b49b45
Customer: Apollo - Rating: [I@243e0b62
Customer: Leslie - Rating: [I@655d6184
```

As I expect the rating to be an array, but it always appears as the weird combination above: [I@2b9fd66a

Could anyone please point out the mistakes that cause the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simplest way to print an array in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/simplest-way-to-print-an-array-in-java)

Comment: Those "weird combinations" are object references.  What type of objects are stored in ratingmap?

Answer (score 6):

Arrays don't override the default [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) method. In order to print a representation of their contents, you can use [`Arrays.toString(int[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int%5B%5D%29).

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8410294/why-does-printlnarray-have-strange-output-ljava-lang-string3e25a5/8410311#8410311) for more details.

Comment: Sorry but I don't really get it, could you please be more specific. Cause I've just started Java. I've tried (for my code): value.toString(int[] value), but it doesn't work :)

Comment: @user1382202 use `Arrays.toString(value)` instead of just `value` in the code of your question.

Comment: Oh, I've figured out, because I didn't import java.util.Arrays; :) Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Value is "int[]", an array of ints. But when you convert that object to string, it doesn't automatically print all the elements of the array for you. It only prints the position in memory of the array, which is what you see.

You need to iterate over the elements of the array in order to print them. Like this:

```
for (int v : value) {
    System.out.println(v);
}
```

Or, as Paul said (Use a Helper class, like Arrays)

Answer (score 1):

What you see is the result of built-in `toString` on integer array types -- it prints "type of array" `[I` part and "reference" part, e.g., `@75b49b45`, which differs on per-instance basis inside the same JVM.

What you need is to manually iterate over array items and print each separately:

```
    int array[] = new int[] {3, 1, 4, 1};
    for (int i : array)
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    System.out.println();
```

Or you may convert array to `List` which has more friendly `toString()` implementation:

```
    int array[] = new int[] {3, 1, 4, 1};
    List<Integer> asList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i : array)
        asList.add(i);
    System.out.println(asList);
```

Regarding starting point, there's explanation why you see `[I` -- it's because arrays have built-in `toString` which is inherited from `toString()` implementation of `Object` class and the latter works by printing type code of class it's called upon, then `@` then internal id of instance of class. And type code for integer arrays is `[I`.

See full description of possible of type codes in javadoc of `Class#getName()` in JDK.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to use `HashMap<String, List<Integer>>` as this will print as you might expect.