# How to add string arrays to array list

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

I'm trying to create an array list of arrays. When I'm done, I want the array list to look like this:

```
[ [Mary] , [Martha,Maggie,Molly] ]
```

I'm trying to accomplish this by first defining "Mary" as a string array of length 1, and defining "Martha, Maggie, Molly" as a string array of length three. Then I attempt to add these arrays to an array list. But alas, the array list will not accept the arrays. Take a look:

```
String[] s1 = new String[1];
String[] s3 = new String[3];

ArrayList<String[]> list1 = new ArrayList<String[]>();

s1[0]="Mary";
s3[0]="Martha";
s3[1]="Maggie";
s3[2]="Molly";

list1.add(s1[0]);
list1.add(s3[0]);
list1.add(s3[1]);
list1.add(s3[2]);
```

Any ideas on how I can add these arrays to list1, in order to form an array list of arrays?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're adding the individual strings to the ArrayList instead of the String arrays that you created.

Try just doing:

```
list1.add(s1);
list1.add(s3);
```

Comment: Thanks. One quick follow-up: when I enter: System.out.println("list1") I don't see the array list I expected. Instead, I see some kind of gibberish. Any idea what's going on with that?

Comment: @kjm it's printing the memory address where `list1` is stored. There isn't a special `println` for `List`s, you have to convert it to a String yourself.

Comment: @kjm See the demo in @dasblinkenlight's answer where he uses a `for` loop to iterate over the elements.

Comment: @kjm See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8410294/why-does-printlnarray-have-strange-output-ljava-lang-string3e25a5) about printing the contents of arrays if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

They aren't being accepted because you are explicitly stating that your `ArrayList` is going to hold `String` arrays, and it appears you are passing in elements from `String` arrays as opposed to the entire array. Instead of adding an element from the array, try adding the entire array:

`list1.add(s1)`

Answer (score -1):

Try this.
Create ArrayList of objects and then assin complete string.

```
ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();       
    String s1[] = new String[1];
    String s3[] = new String[3];

    s1[0]="Mary";
    s3[0]="Martha";
    s3[1]="Maggie";
s3[2]="Molly";

list.add(s1);
```

Answer (score -3):

```
ArrayList<String> Jobs = new ArrayList<String>();    


String programmer = "programmer";
Jobs.add(programmer);


for(String AllJobs : Jobs){
    System.out.println(AllJobs);
}
}//array list //java code
//try this
```

Comment: Please re-read the question, since you've missed what OP asked about. And don't write "code only" answers. Explain your code and why it solves the question.