# How to show maximum same adjacent elements in an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, sorting

Im new to Java and i'm doing array sorting problems and i'm having difficulties with this problem. Searched for simmular or duplicate posts, but didn't seem to find any.

The problem is "Find the most same, adjacent elements in an array and write them in to a new array".

My question is. 
**How can i store most occurued adjacent elements in an array from another array ?**

This is what I have comed up so far.

```
int[] arr= {2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1 ,1}; //test array

int counter=0;
int i = 0;
int length = arr.length;
int[] resultArr=new int[length];



for (i=1; i<length; i++)

    {
   if (arr[i-1]==arr[i])
    {
     counter++;      // Counter to represent maximal adjacent occurred elem.
     resultArr[i] = arr[i]  //Writing elements in result array
    }





} 
 System.out.println(counter);  
 System.out.println(resultArr);
```

---

```
 Input: It is the test array "arr"

 Output 1 : Shoud be 4 representing the maximum of same adjacent elements ( i.e the 2's in the array )
 Output 2 : Must be an array that contains the 4 elements of the array ({2, 2, 2 ,2} )
```

My output is (directly from console)

1
[I@6d06d69c

Comment: What's your question? Why it outputs "[I@6d06d69c" or something else?

Comment: What is maxcounter? Have you tried using a debugger to step through the code line by line and understand what you're doing wrong?

Comment: As @JBNizet mentions use the debugger. Learning to use the debugger takes less effort than typing and formatting posts and waiting for answers

Comment: it sounds like Homeworks :D,if its so you have to try solve it by your self

Comment: @EbrahimPoursadeqi No not at all. The semmester has ended for me a month ago. Im doing this for my own sake. I'm reading a book and solving the problems after it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Break the problem down, first a method to determine when runs of adjacent values stop;

```
private static int runsTo(int[] vals, int index) {
    for (int i = index; i < vals.length - 1; i++) {
        if (vals[i] != vals[i + 1]) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return vals.length;
}
```

Then we can use that with [`Arrays.toString(int[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString-int:A-)<sup>1</sup> as well as [`Arrays.copyOfRange(int[], int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange-int:A-int-int-) like

```
int[] arr = { 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1 };
int index = 0, count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    int r = runsTo(arr, i);
    int c = r - i + 1;
    if (c > count) {
        index = i;
        count = c;
        i += count - 1;
    }
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
System.out.printf("Starting from %d get %d%n", index, count);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, index, index + count)));
```

Which outputs

```
[2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1]
Starting from 5 get 4
[2, 2, 2, 2]
```

<sup>1</sup> Java arrays do not override `toString()`, so you are getting the arrays' hashcode.

Comment: Coincidence, but in the book i found the problem from, suggested doing it in a similar way with using two varriables for the maximal value and where is the current index. Thank you. Works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing two mistakes in your code, first you are using the same index `i` for both your input array `arr` and result array `resultArr`, you should use a different one for `resultArr` like this

```
int resultArrIndex = 0;
for (i=1; i<length; i++)
{
  if (arr[i-1]==arr[i])
  {
    counter++;      // Counter to represent maximal adjacent occurred elem.
    resultArr[resultArrIndex] = arr[i]  //Writing elements in result array
    resultArrIndex++;
  }
}
```

Second this is not the way to print an Array, either you do it in a `for` loop like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < resultArr.length; i++) {
  System.out.println(resultArr[i]);  // will print each in a line
}
```

or like this

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(resultArr));  // Print all in one line
```

Comment: Oh i see is my output the adress of the array in the stack memory ?

Comment: @VeselinLalov it prints a String that describes the identity of the array, in this case the memory location, not the array contents, please check more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8410294/why-does-printlnarray-have-strange-output-ljava-lang-string3e25a5?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution :

```
package com.sujit;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class Test {
    public static int count = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] arr= {2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1 ,1}; //test array
        List<Integer> resultList =Arrays.asList(arr);
        List<Integer> maxOccurence = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();

        for (Integer integer : resultList) {
            set.add(integer);
        }
        for (Integer integer : set) {
            int freq = Collections.frequency(resultList, integer);
            maxOccurence.add(freq);
            System.out.println("Element : "+integer+"  Occurences= "+freq);
        }
        System.out.println(Collections.max(maxOccurence));
    }
}
```