# best way to insert an array to arraylist

Tags: java, android

I tried putting an array into the array list

```
ArrayList <DNA> matingppool;
```

The array is 0 and 1

when I try to show it in logcat in a way

```
population [letsmat [i]].getBiner ()
```

the result is

```
[I @ 25a0766d
```

but when I display it logcat in a way

```
Arrays.toString (population[letsmat[i]].getBiner ())
```

logcat displays

```
[0, 0, 0, 1]
```

the question is

> which is the best way to enter an array into the pooling arraylist so that arraylist returns the array value again?

```
matingppool.add (population [letsmat [i]]);
```

or this one

```
matingppool.add (Arrays.toString (population [letsmat [i]]. getBiner ()));
```

Does " [I @ 25a0766d " represent an array?

Comment: Try adding all the elements in 
`ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.addAll(foo);`

Comment: [I @ 25a0766d is the reference of your array. Use a for loop to iterate and print array items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand what does this present: `[I @ 25a0766d`, go to below link
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8410311/1664430

You can use `Arrays.asList()` and `addAll` method of `List` to achieve this concisely. Below is a sample code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> lst = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] strLst = { "1,", "2", "3" };
    lst.addAll(Arrays.asList(strLst));
    System.out.println(lst);
}
```

And if your purpose it to print/iterate over the `Array`, you can use lambda expression also

```
Arrays.asList(strLst).stream().forEach(System.out::print);
```

Answer (score 1):

there are 2 ways to add arrays in to arraylist,
 -> first one using arrays.asList()

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList=new ArrayList<>();
String[] data=new String[]{"ABC","DEF","GHI"};

arrayList.addAll(Arrays.asList(data));
```

-> second one is using Colliections,

```
    ArrayList<String> arrayList=new ArrayList<>();
    String[] data=new String[]{"ABC","DEF","GHI"};
    Collections.addAll(arrayList, data);
```

this will work for you.

Answer (score -1):

Please go through the example below. 
Override `toString()` method to print Class object in system out.
Comment if something is not clear.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Part1: Add toString() Method in DNA class
    ArrayList<DNA> matingPool = new ArrayList<>();
    matingPool.add(new DNA());
    matingPool.add(new DNA());
    matingPool.add(new DNA());
    System.out.println(matingPool);

    //Part2: use AddAll to add all the objects in one go.
    ArrayList<DNA> newMatingPool = new ArrayList<>(); // You can do new ArrayList<>(matingPool) as well.
    newMatingPool.addAll(matingPool);
    System.out.println(newMatingPool);

}

static class DNA {
    int a;
    String b;

    public DNA() {
        this.a = 10;
        this.b = "BB";
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "DNA{" +
                "a=" + a +
                ", b='" + b + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok as my understanding of your question, Lets say there is a class `User`

```
public class User {

private String userId;
private String userName;
private String userEmail;

public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(String userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getUserEmail() {
    return userEmail;
}

public void setUserEmail(String userEmail) {
    this.userEmail = userEmail;
}

public String toString() {
    return userId + " " + userName + " " + userEmail;
}
}
```

If we create a `ArrayList` of `Class User` and prints it using

```
ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
//Add Items in ArrayList
```

For printing use code

```
for(Users user : users){
Log.d("TAG",user.toString);
}
```

It will print the values in `User` `ArrayList`.**Dont forget to add `toString()` method in your Model class**

Hope it helps you.