# How do I specify an element in a function when calling upon a class's array in Kotlin?

Tags: arrays, class, kotlin

Expectation: console prints: "Making 2 cups of Light coffee"

Reality: Error:(2, 30) Kotlin: The integer literal does not conform to the expected type Array

```
//Class
class CoffeeMaker(
        var strength: Array<String> = arrayOf("Light", "Medium", "Dark"),
        var cups: Int? = null
) {
    fun brewCoffee() {
        println("Making $cups cups of $strength coffee")
    }
}

// Main.kt
fun main() {
    val coffee = CoffeeMaker(0, 2)
    coffee.brewCoffee()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want `strength` to be an option, for how strong the coffee is, and as such one `CoffeeMaker` should have just one `strength` property. An array stores 0 or more things so currently your coffee maker could 0 strengths or a million or whatever.

An Enum represents a single value from a fixed list of options and is probably what you want.  You don't need to refer to the item by its index, just the strength itself

```
enum class CoffeeStrength {  LIGHT, MEDIUM, DARK }

//Class
class CoffeeMaker(
    var strength: CoffeeStrength,
    var cups: Int? = null
) {
    fun brewCoffee() {
        println("Making $cups cups of $strength coffee")
    }
}

// Main.kt
fun main() {
    val coffee = CoffeeMaker(CoffeeStrength.LIGHT, 2)
    coffee.brewCoffee()
}
```

Comment: Mmm, an enum looks like a better fit for this sort of problem than [stringly-typed](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/31876/stringly-typed) code; it gives much stronger compile-time checks, easier debugging, and better readability.

Comment: One clarifying question though, is it possible to convert the text to lowercase? When printed it prints: "Making 2 cups of LIGHT coffee", my hope is to get "Making 2 cups of light coffee"

Comment: Yes. Kotlin coding standards specify the enums should be in caps, but you can add a property to the enum which contains the String you want to print. For example https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/enum-classes.html has an enum Color with an Int property, but it could be a String propety instead

Answer (score 0):

You are passing two integers into the constructor, but your constructor only accepts an Array of Strings and optional an Int.

so what you can do is:

```
// strength 0. 2 cups
val coffee = CoffeeMaker(arrayOf("0"), 2)
```

or

```
// strength 0, 2. null cups
val coffee = CoffeeMaker(arrayOf("0", "2"))
```

The first argument has to be an array of Strings. To make the `0` (integer) a String you need to double quote it. And then you need to wrap it into an array.

[Kotlin doesn't have a literal constructor for arrays](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/plans-for-collection-literals/2049) like other languages have e.g.: `{"0", "2"}` or `["0", "2"]`

Comment: Thanks Simulant! I tried using 

'fun main() {
    val coffee = CoffeeMaker(arrayOf("0"), 2)
    coffee.brewCoffee()
}'

and didn't get any errors but the console output this: "Making 2 cups of [Ljava.lang.String;@1b28cdfa coffee" Any idea what that may be?

Comment: you are printing the name of the reference to the array and not the content of the array. have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/q/8410294/1515052 it's the same for Kotlin as for Java.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the index of the element in the constructor as an argument, you should create a static array in the `companion object` that stores the information and accept an index of type `Int` that could be used later to get element at that index from the `availableStrength` array predefined statically.

```kotlin
class CoffeeMaker(
        var strengthIndex: Int,
        var cups: Int? = null
) {
    fun brewCoffee() {
        println("Making $cups cups of ${availableStrength[strengthIndex]} coffee")
    }

    companion object {
        val availableStrength: Array<String> = arrayOf("Light", "Medium", "Dark")
    }
}
```